# There's any easy way to find a value in a column with two selected repeated values in other column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My problem is, I had a data frame like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 2 |
| d | 2 |

I wish to find values in A which has entries with values 1 and 2 in B. The answer to this problem should be the values (or the rows) with the only values in A being a, b and d. The row with value c should be excluded. Bear in mind that the true dataset is more complex, is a selling table and I want to list only clients who buy simultaneously in months 1 and 2.

Thanks in advance. I solved this in a really ugly and unperformative way, I wish for a better and cleaner way to do this.

Comment: What if for group `A == 'a'` there was also a B row with a value of 3. Would you still want to keep that row since you're keeping the entire group A so long as it has at least one row with 1 and at least one row with 2?

Comment: so the condition is that in 'B', only values of 1 or 2 should exist?

Comment: only the values 1 and 2 should exists. I wish two know the people who bought things in two months consecutively as bought a stuff in month 1 and other stuff in month 2.

Comment: @JoãoPauloAndrade so you've gotten 3 pretty good solutions but what I can say is that they all make rather different assumptions. None of these assumptions are apparent given your sample data, but it would be good to know a bit more about some of your specific edge cases. That is, it might be worth stating that either these circumstances aren't possible in your data, or how they should be handled with a more complete test-case: 1) A group with three rows and B values 1,2,3. A group with three rows and B values 1,2,2. The 3 current solutions will all behave differently in these situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mask, keeping only rows where B is `1` or `2` and the second part keeps only groups that have at least a single row that is `1` and `2`. You can scale this if you want with `np.logical_and.reduce` to save some writing.

```
import numpy as np

mask = (df['B'].isin([1, 2])
        & df['B'].eq(1).groupby(df['A']).transform('any')
        & df['B'].eq(2).groupby(df['A']).transform('any'))

df[mask]
```

---

```
   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  1
3  d  1
4  a  2
5  b  2
6  d  2
```

---

More scaleable, just add values to the list:

```
import numpy as np
vals = [1, 2]

mask = (df['B'].isin(vals)
        & np.logical_and.reduce([df['B'].eq(val).groupby(df['A']).transform('any')
                                 for val in vals]))
```

Comment: it worked! thank you very much. My solution was to ugly. Now i have a really good performance on it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use `groupby.transform` and `loc`, as if i'm getting you your request is quite simple:

```
import pandas as pd
res = (df.loc[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('size')>=2]).sort_values(by='A')

   A  B
0  a  1
4  a  2
1  b  1
5  b  2
3  d  1
6  d  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of great answers already, here is my approach to solving the problem

```
import pandas as pd

# Setup
A = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "d"]
B = [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2]

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": A, "B": B})

# Keep only values less than or equal than 2, representing month 1 and 2
filter = df[df["B"] <= 2]
# Sort the values by column A and B
sort = df.sort_values(by=["A", "B"])
# Group them and count number of appeareances
groupby_count = sort.groupby(["A"], as_index=False).agg(count=("A", "count"))
# Only keep appearances equal to 2, as that would imply appearances of month 1 and 2
print(groupby_count[groupby_count["count"] == 2])
```

output:

```
   A  count
0  a      2
1  b      2
3  d      2
```